# Issue in fitting and tuning a workflow model with tidymodels

Tags: performance, knn, hyperparameters, tidymodels

I'm trying to create a knn model, fitting it and tuning huperparameters with the tidymodels' tools.

After creating a recipe, a model (with the number of neighbors as hyperparameter to tune), I've divided training set into 5 folds in order to cross validate the choice of the best hyperparameter.

Then, I've put the model and the recipe together in a workflow, fitted the model with the cross validation folds.

At this stage I receive a message error:" → A | error:   Assigned data `orig_rows` must be compatible with existing data" that I can't understand what is caused by.

Can anybody help me to understand what's wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
# loading dataset
orange <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/orange_juice_withmissing.csv')

# data partitioning
orange_split <- initial_split(orange,
                              prop = 0.8,
                              strata=Purchase)

trainOrangeOrigin <- training(orange_split)

testOrangeOrigin <- testing(orange_split)

# preprocess recipe
recipeKnnTunedPrep <- trainOrangeOrigin|>
  recipe(Purchase ~.)|>
  step_impute_knn(all_numeric_predictors())|>
  step_percentile(all_numeric_predictors())|>
  step_corr(all_numeric_predictors(),
            threshold=0.7)|>
  step_percentile(all_numeric_predictors())|>
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors())|>
  step_corr(all_numeric_predictors(), threshold=0.7)|>
  step_range(all_numeric_predictors(), min=0, max=1)

# model and hyperparameters selection
modelKnnTunedPrep <-
  nearest_neighbor(neighbors = tune())|>
  set_engine("kknn")|>
  set_mode("classification")

# regular grid of values for hyperparameter tuning
gridKnn <- grid_regular(neighbors(),
                        levels = 5)

# cross-validation folds for tuning
set.seed(234, sample.kind = "Rounding")
folds <- vfold_cv(trainOrangeOrigin, v=5)

# Workflow creation, fitting and model plotting
set.seed(345, sample.kind = "Rounding")

WF_BaseKnnTunedPrep <- workflow()|>
  add_recipe(recipeKnnTunedPrep)|>
  add_model(modelKnnTunedPrep)

# fitting
resultWF_KnnTunedPrep <- 
  WF_BaseKnnTunedPrep|> 
  tune_grid(resamples = folds,
            control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE),
            grid = gridKnn)
```

This is the error message that I get back from R:

```
→ A | error:   Assigned data `orig_rows` must be compatible with existing data.
               ✖ Existing data has 170 rows.
               ✖ Assigned data has 171 rows.
               ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
               Caused by error in `vectbl_recycle_rhs_rows()`:
               ! Can't recycle input of size 171 to size 170.
There were issues with some computations   A: x2
```

I was expecting a regular execution of the code without any warning/error message, as it has happen with the same dataset with a different model (decision tree).

Comment: Some issues with the data should be sorted out before posting.

Comment: `StoreID` is an integer, but you treat it as a numeric predictor. It could be converted to a factor to be used appropriately. You've also duplicated the integer column into another called `STORE` and then made a specific dummy variable for `Store7`.

Comment: Also, it looks like you have different features for the two classes. This will only work with your training set since new data can't have those features (since the outcome is unknown). You should probably undo that.

Comment: A few recipe steps are repeated. That's probably not good.

Comment: Thanks @topepo. Repeated recipe steps: my mistake. I've tried different orders of preprocessing steps and this has caused some confusion. StoreID, STORE and Store7 features: there's something I've misunderstood in the dataset which I'll try to make clearer and simpler. As far as the "different features for the two classes", I have not understood your point. Could you tell me what I should undo specifically? Next time I'll try to pay more attention: I have really read over and over the code before posting. Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: Update. I've followed @topepo's advice regarding data cleaning (StoreID, Store7 and STORE) keeping only StoreID column and errors no longer appear. I still can't understand  the suggestion about "different features for the two classes". Thank you for helping me.